# Date parse string in `dd-M-yyyy` format

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

I need to create new Date from a string in format: `dd-M-yyyy`

example:

```
var dateStr = '16-Sep-2012';
var date = new Date(dateStr);
```

However IE isn't very happy with it and considers `date` value as `NaN`.
Would somebody recommend me or give me a reliable parser for that?
10x for your kind help, BR

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

Comment: Check this out: http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/

Comment: 10x for your help, both of you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Date.parse` function, and then call the new Date function on that variable. See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TCnhe/2/).

```
var date = Date.parse('16-Sep-2012');
var formatted_date = new Date(date);
```

Using the [jQuery globalization plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), you can parse dates using Globalizaiton.parseDate. The plugin adds support for IE.

Comment: 10x for your kind help but IE8 parser does not support it and that's the problem in the first place :(

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery globalisation plugin - http://github.com/jquery/globalize - and see updated answer.